# Expectation number of random points exactly on their convex hull

Tags: probability, geometry, expectation, geometric-probability

Suppose there are n random points uniformly distributed in a square, what's the expectation of the number of the points located exactly on the edge (or being vertexes) of their convex hull? What if they are all integral points?

Comment: @CalvinLin Thanks.I have updated the description.

Comment: Sorry for this stupid question: what do you mean by integral points? Do you mean points with integer coordinates? In this case the answer will depends a lot on the size of your square. If you mean the coordinates are rational then I guess it does not change the result.

Comment: @GillesBonnet There is no such thing as being uniformly distributed on the points with rational coordinates in a square.

Comment: The number of points located exactly on the edge of their convex hull is almost surely zero. The expected number of points which are vertices of their convex hull is the total number of points, say $n$, times the probability that one point is not in the convex hull $C_{n-1}$ of $n-1$ other points. This probability is proportional to the area of the complement of $C_{n-1}$.

Comment: @Did thanks for your (first) comment. I actually never thought at this problem. Is it because rational points are countable so the measure of the rational points is the (countable) sum of the measure of each point, which is zero?

Comment: @GillesBonnet Yes.